# How to run the command using subprocess with timeout intervals in python

Tags: subprocess, python-3.6

I'm trying to execute the python script using subprocess module .It works well without timeout. Here the python script i used to run with subprocess  :

**sample.py**

```
count=0
while(True):
    print(count)
    count+=1
```

The problem is sample.py execute infinitely  .So i'm trying to set a timeout to run this script .I have googled and some of them suggested to use check_output() function to obtain the results using timeout .So i changed ,

`out = check_output('python3 /home/gomathi/sample.py', stderr=STDOUT, timeout=5,shell=True)`

But that won't work for me ,it still execute the sample.py even after the timeout.

What should i use to resolve this issue ?

**python version : 3.6.7**

`out=subprocess.Popen(['python3 /home/gomathi/sample.py'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)`

Then i changed subprocess to check_output function :

`out = check_output('python3 /home/gomathi/sample.py', stderr=STDOUT, timeout=5,shell=True)`

I expect the script(sample.py) should stop running once it reached it's timeout.

Comment: same problem here. Have you found a fix?